# How do I convert Markdown to Html using Text.Pandoc (Haskell)?

Tags: haskell, markdown, pandoc

I have the following code:

```
import Text.Pandoc

myWriterOptions = defaultWriterOptions 
    { writerHtml5 = True 
    , writerStrictMarkdown = False
    }

markdownToHtml :: String -> Html
markdownToHtml = writeHtml myWriterOptions . readMarkdown defaultParserState
```

If I apply it to a markdown string:
 `"header\n=======\nA line of text.\n### A list ###\n- apple\n- orange\n- pear"`

I end up with:
`"<h1 id=\"header\">header</h1>\n<p>A line of text. ### A list ### - apple - orange - pear</p>"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me, and so does the output. I get the same output from [Try Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try).

If you add newlines before the second heading and list, then it produces the output you're looking for. I wouldn't be surprised if other Markdown implementations require blank lines, too; after all, it would be pretty annoying if starting a line with a hyphen started a new list (think line wrapping).

Comment: Okay, most other implementations do not require that, which is why I was confused.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no formal specification of Markdown that I know of, so all the implementations are essentially imitating [the original Perl implementation](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/). You might want to [report a bug](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/bugs.html) if you think this behaviour is undesirable.

Comment: @ehird You were correct so I guess it should come as no surprise to you, markdown's original description requires the blank lines:

> "A paragraph is simply one or more consecutive lines of text,separated by one or more blank lines." [syntax][1]

  [1]: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax

Answer (score 1):

Pandoc API has changed a bit. This works for me:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module PandocDemo where

import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import Data.Profunctor (dimap)
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as T

import Text.Pandoc

markdownToHtml :: Text -> Text
markdownToHtml = dimap inp out markdownToHtml'
  where
    inp = T.unpack
    out = either (("Error: " <>) . tshow) T.pack

markdownToHtml' :: String -> Either PandocError String
markdownToHtml' s = writeHtmlString opts <$> readMarkdown def s
  where
    opts = def { writerHtml5 = True }
```